# Род имени существительного

Tags: синтаксис

Если имя существительное в родительном падеже, то можно ли определить род?

Answer (score 1):

Можно в принципе. Большая часть существительных мужского рода в род. падеже ед.ч. оканчивается на -а/-я; тогда как существительные женского рода оканчивается на -ы/-и.